# Prove that complement of given set has measure zero.

Tags: measure-theory

Let $S\subset \mathbb{R}^2\times\mathbb{R}^2$ be defined as set of all pairs $(v_1,v_2)$ satisying the following 2 properties:

1. No two vectors in $\{(1,0),v_1,v_2\}$ are dependent.
2. If $(1,0)$ = a$v_1$ + b$v_2$, then $b/a$ is irrational.

Show that $S^c$ has measure zero.

I have proved that condition-$1$ holds for almost every $(v_1,v_2)\in \mathbb{R}^2 \times \mathbb{R}^2$, but i am not able to prove it for condition-$2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each rational $q,$ define the set $S_q$ of $(v_1,v_2)$ such that $(0,1)=av_1+bv_2$ for some $a,b$ with $b=qa.$ This is contained in a proper affine subspace of $\mathbb R^4$ so has measure zero. So $S^c$ is a countable union of countable sets: the $S_q,$ together with the set of points not satisfying the first condition.

Comment: Why is $S_q$ contained in some proper affine subspace of $\mathbb{R}^4$.

Comment: @Mr.X: dividing through by $a$ and taking the first component shows it's contained in the set of $(v_1,v_2)$ such that $(v_1)_1=-q(v_2)_1.$ (Note $a$ must be non-zero because $1=a((v_1)_1+q(v_2)_1).$)